# Produce a file that contains names of all empty subfolders

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to write a script that takes a name of a folder as a command line argument and produces a file that contains the names of all subfolders with size 0 (empty subfolder). This is what I got:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Name of a folder'
read FOLDER

for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do 
     echo "$entry"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you accept the answer which suggests to use `find` instead.  But just to be complete, here is some feedback on your code.

- You read the input directory into `FOLDER` but then never use this variable.
- As an aside, don't use uppercase for your private variables; this is reserved for system variables.
- You have unpaired quotes in the prompt string.  If the opening quote is double, you need to close with a double quote, or vice versa for single quotes.
- You loop over directory entries, but do nothing to isolate just the ones which are directories, let alone empty directories.
- Finally, nothing in your script uses Bash-only facilities, so it would be safe and somewhat more portable to use `#!/bin/sh`

Now, looping over directories can be done by using `search_dir/*/` instead of just `search_dir/*`; and finding out which ones are empty can be done by checking whether a wildcard within the directory returns just the directory itself.  (This assumes default globbing behavior -- with `nullglob` you would make a wildcard with no matches expand to an empty list, but this is problematic in some scenarios so it's not the default.)

```
#!/bin/bash

# read -p is not POSIX
read -p "Name of a folder" search_dir

for dir in "$search_dir"/*/
do
     # [[ is Bash only
     if [[ "$dir"/* = "$dir/*" ]]; then  # Notice tricky quoting
         echo "$dir"
     fi
done
```

Using the wildcard expansion with `[` is problematic because it is not prepared to deal with a wildcard expansion -- you get "too many arguments" if the wildcard expands into more than one filename -- so I'm using the somewhat more mild-tempered Bash replacement `[[` which copes just fine with this.  Alternatively, you could use `case`, which I would actually prefer here; but I've stuck to `if` in order to make only minimal changes to your script.

Comment: Revisiting two and a half years later, this has a bug; it thinks the directory is empty if it contains exactly one file whose name is literally `*`. Probably refactor to use `-e` on the first argument returned by the wildcard instead.

Answer (score 4):

your script doesn't have the logic you intended.  `find` command has a feature for this

```
$ find path/to/dir -type d -empty
```

will print empty directories starting from the given path/to/dir